# Issue with views and php

Tags: views

i'm using a view thats pulls data from a certain node via refference and i show non logged in users a error that they need to login, but i need to show a special node/add link with the nid in it. i'v got the code and it works without the if statement, in the if statement, my code is not working..

```
<?php global $user;if (!$user->uid){print '<div class="messages error"><h4 class="alert-heading logged_out">Oops!</h4><p>tekst hier</p></div>';}else{
 (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {  $nid = arg(1);print '<a class="btn" href='/node/add/album&field_band[]=$nid'>Voeg een album toe!<a/>';} ?>



<?php  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {  $nid = arg(1);print '<a class="btn"  href='/node/add/album&field_band[]=$nid'>Voeg een album toe!<a/>';} ?>
```

the code above works, but not when its in the if/else block...

Please note that i don't have great knowledge about php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should write the if-else structure like:

```
<?php 
global $user;
if (!$user->uid) {
   print '<div class="messages error"><h4 class="alert-heading logged_out">Oops!</h4><p>tekst hier</p></div>';
}
else if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {  
    $nid = arg(1);
    print '<a class="btn" href='/node/add/album&field_band[]=$nid'>Voeg een album toe!<a/>';
}
```

?>

Note that after 'else' you want to test some conditions so you need to put an 'if' statement in front of your test.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `if` before the beginning of your second line of code; you should be getting a fatal error for invalid syntax, unless it's being suppressed somehow.

Try changing the first two lines to:

```
<?php 
global $user;
if (!$user->uid) { 
  print '<div class="messages error"><h4 class="alert-heading logged_out">Oops!</h4><p>tekst hier</p></div>';
} else {
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) { 
    $nid = arg(1);
    print '<a class="btn" href='/node/add/album&field_band[]=$nid'>Voeg een album toe!<a/>';
  } 
}
?>
```

Or go with Gabriel's solution to use an `else if`, it's more efficient anyway.

Comment: I tried al of the above, but it won't work for some reason... the else switch works when i just add tekst after the else, but the php snippet not, hmm